# Capture Custom Events from Individual pages

Tags: visual-studio, azure, azure-application-insights, custom-events, azure-analysis-services

I Have my application set up with azure app insights, and I am capturing the custom events from across the application, there are events that can be triggered from multiple pages. So I am wondering is there any way in azure dashboard I could segregate events by page ?

Eg-  Download button can be triggered from Search page and also from Collections page

So is there any way I could have events from Search Page shown individually and same with collections page ?

I am new to azure app insights, help is appreciated.

my current custom events look like this [image]

It is very hard to read the events on page basis.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> there are events that can be triggered from multiple pages.So I am wondering is there any way in azure dashboard I could segregate events by page ?

I suggest you could choose specific event name and operation name in **Filters** to achieve your goal:

[image]

You could also segregate events in Application Insights [Analytics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-analytics).

[image]

> So is there any way I could have events from Search Page shown individually and same with collections page ?

You could filter the  events by selecting  specific event name:

[image]

Comment: Yes, this helps.

Thank you so much :)